# asp.net masterpage video background

Tags: c#, video, background

Does anyone know how to set the background of my webpage to a video in asp.net c# I can get the video to play on the page but it will not set up as a full screen background with my content on top.

Thanks

Comment: checkout this link perhaps you could make some little code modifications http://forums.asp.net/t/1641678.aspx

Comment: An option would be to utilize HTML5 to display a video in the background.

Comment: Can you please direct me on how to implement the ideo background in asp.net usning html5? If I use html5 it places the video where I place it in the body not underneath reguardless of what css i use:   awesome_video 
    { position: absolute; 
      top: 0; 
     left: 0; 
      width: 100%; 
      height: 100%; 
      z-index:-20000;

    }

Comment: Apologies, I cannot edit the last comment:
Can you please direct me on how to implement the video background in asp.net using html5? If I use html5 it places the video where I place it in the body not underneath regardless of what css i use:
    

    .awesome_video 
    { position: absolute; 
      top: 0; 
     left: 0; 
      width: 100%; 
      height: 100%; 
      z-index:-20000;

    }

    <video autoplay loop poster="test.jpg" id="awesome-video">
    <source src="test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>